# Indenting and aligning lines after the first

Tags: html, css

I have the following block of text.

[image]

I would like to indent the yellow text, so that all the yellow lines are lined up on their left edges.

Per another answer, I tried `text-indent:-3em;padding-left:3em;`, but this only affects subsequent lines after the first.

Can this be accomplished using CSS? Or do I need to construct another table?

Here is one example. It is just a single line of markup.

```
<td>PC: <span style="font-size:smaller;">US 104 Key (ANSI), DE 105 Key (ISO), FR 105 Key (ISO), UK 105 Key (ISO), ES 105 Key (ISO), US 104 Key (Dvorak)</span><br/>Mac: <span style="font-size:smaller;">US 109 Key (A1048), US 109 Key (A1243), UK 110 Key (A1048)</span></td>
```

except that I deleted the links when posting it.

Comment: Can you share any code snippet or fiddle for more clarifications? Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Yes I have added some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That not-working solution you are quoting can be improved and extended to achieve what you are after:

```css
.x {
  position: relative;
  left: 3em;
  width: calc(100% - 3em);
  color: green;
}

.y {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -3em;
  width: 3em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div class="y">PC:</div>lkj sdflkj sdflkj sdflkj sdlfkj lsdkfj lksdjf lkjsd flkj sdflkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sldkfj lsdkjf lskdjf lkj sdflkj sdflkj sdflkj sdlfkj lsdkfj lksdjf lkjsd flkj sdflkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sldkfj lsdkjf lskdjf lkj sdflkj sdflkj sdflkj sdlfkj
  lsdkfj lksdjf lkjsd flkj sdflkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sldkfj lsdkjf lskdjf </div>
<div class="x">
  <div class="y">MAC:</div>lkj sdflkj sdflkj sdflkj sdlfkj lsdkfj lksdjf lkjsd flkj sdflkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sldkfj lsdkjf lskdjf lkj sdflkj sdflkj sdflkj sdlfkj lsdkfj lksdjf lkjsd flkj sdflkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sldkfj lsdkjf lskdjf lkj sdflkj sdflkj sdflkj sdlfkj
  lsdkfj lksdjf lkjsd flkj sdflkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sldkfj lsdkjf lskdjf lkj sdflkj sdflkj sdflkj sdlfkj lsdkfj lksdjf lkjsd flkj sdflkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sdlfkj sldkfj lsdkjf lskdjf </div>
```

Comment: Can I replace `div` with `dl`, `dt` and `dd`?

Comment: Did you try it? ;-)

Comment: In future if `PC` or `MAC` replace with long text like `Stackoverflow` it'll overlap with the text.

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui Yes, *IF*. Anyway, you can adjust the `em` value to what ever is needed. The more flexible  solution (as the OP already writes in the question) would be to use a table, but obviously the OP is looking for a non-table solution for exactly THIS situation (i.e. PC/MAC).

Comment: Suppose there are two headings 1. `PC` and 2. `Stackoverflow` if you change `em` value it'll effect all items and we have extra space between `PC` and `text`.

Comment: Yes - otherwise it wouldn't look good. There's also a difference in length between "MAC" and "PC". It wouldn't look good if you had different indents there.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution but jumping first line:

```css
span {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 3em;
  font-size: smaller; 
}
```

```html
<td>PC:
  <span>US 104 Key (ANSI), DE 105 Key (ISO), FR 105 Key (ISO), 
  UK 105 Key (ISO), ES 105 Key (ISO), US 104 Key (Dvorak)</span>
  <br/>Mac:
  <span>US 109 Key (A1048), US 109 Key (A1243), UK 110 Key (A1048)</span>
</td>
```

Comment: This looks very similar to the default rendering of the description list HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Make it **sweet** and **simple**. Thanks

```css
.box {
  color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box .heading {
  color: #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="heading">Heading 1:</div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="heading">Heading 1:</div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
</div>
```